# How do I resolve this Unchecked cast warning?

Tags: java, generics

This line gives me the unchecked cast warning

```
this.gameSocket = (U) game.getGameSocket();
```

SocketHandler.java:

```
public class SocketHandler<T extends Game, U extends GameSocket> extends 
Listener
{
    protected T game;
    protected U gameSocket;

    public SocketHandler(T game)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.gameSocket = (U) game.getGameSocket();
    }
}
```

Game.java:

```
public class Game<T extends GameSocket>
{
    protected T gameSocket;

    public T getGameSocket()
    {
        return gameSocket;
    }

    public Game()
    {

    }
}
```

GameSocket.java:

```
public class GameSocket<T extends Game>
{
    protected T game;
    protected int port;

    public GameSocket(T game, int port)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.port = port;
    }
}
```

I feel as if there is a generic circulation issue here but the code works fine. However, there is probably a better way of doing what I am doing here.

Comment: so, your game has socket and at the same time socket has game, right?

Comment: Yes correct. They have one-to-one relationship due to their dependability with each other.

Comment: Can you explain why `Game` and `GameSocket` seem to have a circular depedency?

Comment: what methods of the socket will be called by game and what methods of the game will be called by socket?

Comment: I use the game class inside the socket to be able to handle packets from the client and process it. The socket class will need to reference to the game class to do that. The game class needs the referenced socket class to initialize the socket and bind it.

Comment: why do you need sockethandler then?

Comment: To receive the packets and check for incoming connection and disconnection of the clients.

Comment: socket handler should handle both (connections and packets), thus socket does not require dependency on game

Comment: I can probably remove the gameSocket reference from the SocketHandler class which mainly is the purpose of caching.

Comment: so, socket handler will not know about socket?

Comment: SocketHandler knows about the Game class which knows about the socket. I know it seems a bit backwards so I will have to choose another design pattern.

Comment: I solved your problem by removing the circular generic dependency below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a generic loop: the generic type of GameSocket extends Game, but the generic type of Game extends GameSocket!

To fix this, I recommend changing `GameSocket`'s class declaration to:

```
public class GameSocket<T> {
    ...
}
```

Then, you can change `Game`'s class declaration to:

```
public class Game<T extends GameSocket<T>> {
    ...
}
```

Finally, you can change `SocketHandler`'s class declaration to:

```
public class SocketHandler<T extends Game<U>, U extends GameSocket<U>> extends Listener {
    ...
}
```

This makes everything type-safe and the warning is gone.

You can even remove the explicit cast `(U)` when retrieving `game.getGameSocket()`

Comment: That did solve the issue with the circular dependency and I have already changed the design pattern due to over-complexity. However in the future if I am required to have a circular dependency with generics, I can always follow up this solution. Thanks!